# Detected JDK Version: 1.6.0-24 is not in the allowed range 1.7

Tags: java, maven, centos

When I ran the command

```
mvn clean package
```

I am getting error:

```
Detected JDK Version: 1.6.0-24 is not in the allowed range 1.7.
```

How to fix the above error? I tried to check jdk version isntalled and got this

```
java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

how to fix this?

Comment: Please provides the result for `mvn -v`. It will tell us which JDK version that the Maven uses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally when execute the `mvn -v` you may see something like

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 
                    2013-02-19 20:51:28+0700)
Maven home: C:\Java.Application\Apache\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_15, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Java.Application\Sun\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MS874
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

If the result point to the `JDK Version: 1.6.0-24` or other than your expect. Please simply set the `JAVA_HOME` to your `JDK Version: 1.7.0_03` instead.

I hope this may help.

Comment: I need to run command using sudo then it works "sudo -i mvn clean package"

Comment: If you set the java home in the command line you need to open and close the cli

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your environment (PATH) is set up to use the JDK version that you want to use for compiling. You can check this by running the following in the shell or command window where you want to run Maven:

```
java -version
javac -version
```

Make sure that both `java` and `javac` are pointing to the correct version. It's possible that you have a 1.7 JRE (which does not include the compiler) and a 1.6 JDK (which includes the compiler) and the wrong one is being used.

If necessary, adjust your `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables.

Just noticed that you're on CentOS - it's possible that `java` and `javac` point to different versions. Use the `alternatives` command to check that, see here for an example: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/JavaRuntimeEnvironment - you will have to check both the `java` and the `javac` command.

Answer (score 2):

Check your JRE System Library in Eclipse.  Does it show jdk1.6.0-24?

For me I had to right click the JRE System Library and go to Build Path -> Configure Build Path, in the Libraries tab I had to click JRE System Library and edit it.  I set it to the Workspace Default JRE, which for me is jdk1.7.0_80 (not sure why it wasn't set to that already).