# Detected JDK Version: 15.0.2 is not in the allowed range [1.8.0-101,1.8.9999]

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I have following problem that have been reported several times ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568835/detected-jdk-version-1-6-0-24-is-not-in-the-allowed-range-1-7), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968515/detected-maven-version-3-0-5-is-not-in-the-allowed-range-3-2), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134155/building-with-jdk-version-11-0-1-is-not-supported-please-install-jdk-version), [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860547/jdk-version-not-in-allowed-range), [link5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63629119/detected-jdk-version-11-0-8-is-not-in-the-allowed-range-1-8-0-101-1-8-9999), etc). But I could not find a clear answer.

I just edited the name of project and basic information in the template of this project [example-imagej-command](https://github.com/imagej/example-imagej-command);

when I try to build with Maven in eclipse;

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/cosacak/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/cosacak/eclipse/java-2020-12/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/cosacak/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/cosacak/eclipse/java-2020-12/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< de.kizillab.org:MyExamplePlugin >-------------------
[INFO] Building My Example Plugin 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-rules) @ MyExamplePlugin ---
[INFO] Adding ignore: module-info
[INFO] Adding ignore: META-INF/versions/*/module-info
[INFO] Adding ignore: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.*.package-info
[INFO] Adding ignore: org.apache.spark.unused.UnusedStubClass
[INFO] Adding ignore: org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl
[INFO] Adding ignore: org.junit.runner.Runner
[INFO] Adding ignore: module-info
[WARNING] Rule 2: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed with message:
Detected JDK Version: 15.0.2 is not in the allowed range [1.8.0-101,1.8.9999].
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.330 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-31T02:49:00+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-rules) on project MyExamplePlugin: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Now if I run as Java Application using eclipse;

```
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.bushe.swing.event.EventService).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[ERROR] Cannot create plugin: class='org.scijava.plugins.scripting.javascript.JavaScriptScriptLanguage', name='JavaScript', priority=0.0, enabled=true, pluginType=ScriptLanguage
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such script engine: javascript
    at org.scijava.script.AdaptedScriptLanguage.findFactory(AdaptedScriptLanguage.java:152)
    at org.scijava.script.AdaptedScriptLanguage.<init>(AdaptedScriptLanguage.java:74)
    at org.scijava.plugins.scripting.javascript.JavaScriptScriptLanguage.<init>(JavaScriptScriptLanguage.java:59)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:350)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at org.scijava.plugin.PluginInfo.createInstance(PluginInfo.java:306)
    at org.scijava.plugin.DefaultPluginService.createInstance(DefaultPluginService.java:237)
    at org.scijava.plugin.DefaultPluginService.createInstances(DefaultPluginService.java:226)
    at org.scijava.plugin.DefaultPluginService.createInstancesOfType(DefaultPluginService.java:217)
    at org.scijava.plugin.AbstractSingletonService.initInstances(AbstractSingletonService.java:138)
    at org.scijava.plugin.AbstractSingletonService.getInstances(AbstractSingletonService.java:77)
    at org.scijava.plugin.SingletonService.lambda$initialize$0(SingletonService.java:97)
    at org.scijava.object.ObjectIndex.resolvePending(ObjectIndex.java:388)
    at org.scijava.object.ObjectIndex.get(ObjectIndex.java:133)
    at org.scijava.object.DefaultObjectService.getObjects(DefaultObjectService.java:87)
    at org.scijava.display.DefaultDisplayService.getDisplays(DefaultDisplayService.java:166)
    at org.scijava.ui.DefaultUIService.showUI(DefaultUIService.java:159)
    at org.scijava.ui.DefaultUIService.showUI(DefaultUIService.java:142)
    at de.kizillab.org.MyExamplePlugin.main(MyExamplePlugin.java:85)
[ERROR]: Cannot locate JRE jar in C:\Users\cosacak\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955\jre
[ERROR] Cannot create plugin: class='org.scijava.ui.swing.script.languagesupport.JavaLanguageSupportPlugin', priority=0.0, enabled=true, pluginType=LanguageSupportPlugin
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: info cannot be null
    at org.fife.rsta.ac.java.JarManager.addClassFileSource(JarManager.java:157)
    at org.fife.rsta.ac.java.JarManager.addCurrentJreClassFileSource(JarManager.java:193)
    at org.scijava.ui.swing.script.languagesupport.JavaLanguageSupportPlugin.<init>(JavaLanguageSupportPlugin.java:56)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:350)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at org.scijava.plugin.PluginInfo.createInstance(PluginInfo.java:306)
    at org.scijava.plugin.DefaultPluginService.createInstance(DefaultPluginService.java:237)
    at org.scijava.plugin.DefaultPluginService.createInstances(DefaultPluginService.java:226)
    at org.scijava.plugin.DefaultPluginService.createInstancesOfType(DefaultPluginService.java:217)
    at org.scijava.plugin.AbstractSingletonService.initInstances(AbstractSingletonService.java:138)
    at org.scijava.plugin.AbstractSingletonService.getInstances(AbstractSingletonService.java:77)
    at org.scijava.plugin.SingletonService.lambda$initialize$0(SingletonService.java:97)
    at org.scijava.object.ObjectIndex.resolvePending(ObjectIndex.java:388)
    at org.scijava.object.ObjectIndex.get(ObjectIndex.java:133)
    at org.scijava.object.DefaultObjectService.getObjects(DefaultObjectService.java:87)
    at org.scijava.display.DefaultDisplayService.getDisplays(DefaultDisplayService.java:166)
    at org.scijava.ui.DefaultUIService.showUI(DefaultUIService.java:159)
    at org.scijava.ui.DefaultUIService.showUI(DefaultUIService.java:142)
    at de.kizillab.org.MyExamplePlugin.main(MyExamplePlugin.java:85)
[INFO] Found 10 JHotDraw adapters.
```

Comment: The build script obviously want to enforce that you **build using Java 8**, so how about you honor the restriction and install Java 8 and use that when building? --- As for the `No such script engine: javascript` error, the JavaScript scripting engine was removed in Java 15. If you change to use the Java 8 the program obviously wants, you'll get your JavaScript too.

Comment: Here is the java version, do I have to downgrade to 8 or is there a way to do it in eclipse installation: `java version "16" 2021-03-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16+36-2231)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16+36-2231, mixed mode, sharing)`

Comment: I told you to install Java 8. If you need help installing Java 8, then create a new question and ask for it, but asking if you need to downgrade to 8 when I already told you to install 8 is just ... *(sorry, can't find word to use)* --- Yes, there is a way to use Java 8 in Eclipse. But how much help is it knowing that? Wouldn't it be better to ask *how* to do it with Eclipse? Of course, you could just do a web search to find the answer, but let's not get into that. --- Perhaps you should consider how better to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For window users, if you have Maven project, Maven is also available and can be used to compile/package as can be done on Linux (see my answer above). As a result, in case one has the problem above while building a project in eclipse and does not have Linux as well, can use Maven on windows as well.

Now I am writing my scripts/projects in eclipse and using Maven command to compile/package as below;

Download Maven zip file from [here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and unzip it anywhere on windows, does not have to be in your project folder. Add maven `\bin` in PATH. The bin file has `maven.cmd` in e.g., `apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin` folder after unzipping.

now open command terminal in windows, use `cd` to navigate to the project folder which have `pom.xml` file as well. In my case;

```
cd Documents\eclipse-workspace\example-imagej-command-master

mvn compile
mvn package
```

it works as well on windows.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to eclipse, one may simply use Maven on linux or any operating system that has Maven installed.

Here the version on linux is :

```
>java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_282-8u282-b08-0ubuntu1~20.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.282-b08, mixed mode)
```

and maven version is:

```
>mvn -version

Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_282, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.4.0-60-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

now simply running:

```
mvn compile
mvn package
```

solves the problem.

if I find a solution with eclipse or netbeans, I will post the answer for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

And finally, I could solve the problem with eclipse on windows. In order to build the package the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63629119/detected-jdk-version-11-0-8-is-not-in-the-allowed-range-1-8-0-101-1-8-9999) worked for eclipse on Windows:

In brief;

Go to;

```
windows -> preferences -> Installed JREs
```

then press `Add -> Start VM` press `Next`,    Choose JRE home by "`Directory`" as `path2Fiji\Fiji\java\win64\jdk1.8.0_172`

Finally, select jdk from FiJi and "`Apply and Close`".

Now, eclipse should be able build Maven project on Windows.